# cannot call wkhtmltopdf in php

Tags: php, shell

I can call this line in terminal directly:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf http://www.baidu.com /home/azureuser/webhtml.pdf
```

It works ok, and outputs the `pdf` in the `home` directory.

However, I try it in `PHP`,

```
echo shell_exec('xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" wkhtmltopdf http://www.baidu.com /home/azureuser/webhtml.pdf');
```

The output is :

> Loading page (1/2) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [===============> ] 25%
>   [=====================> ] 36% [=======================> ] 39%
>   [========================> ] 41% [==================================>
>   ] 58% [====================================> ] 60%
>   [======================================> ] 64%
>   [==============================================> ] 78%
>   [================================================> ] 80%
>   [==================================================> ] 84%
>   [=====================================================> ] 89%
>   [======================================================> ] 90%
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   Printing pages (2/2) QPainter::begin(): Returned false [> ] Done

and no file outputs, What is wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions?

Comment: When you go to the adress, do you get the file then?